# VB6 Program not working in Windows Me

Tags: windows, vb6

I have written a program in VB6. When I compile it and send it to my friend, he says it is not working. He (like me) has Windows Me.

Why my programs are not working there? Should he install something or what?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "it's not working"?

Comment: The problem is on line 42 of your code.

Oh, you didn't post any code. That might be the problem. ;)

At the very least, an explanation of what happens when your friend tries to run your application would be helpful. Any less and we're just guessing.

Comment: VB6 on Windows Me? Dude, it's time to upgrade.

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/632808/why-is-vb6-still-so-widely-used/632915#632915

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He should install Microsoft Visual Basic run-time files that all applications created with Visual Basic 6.0 need in order to run.

You can get it from [Microsoft's Download Center](http://download.microsoft.com/download/vb60pro/install/6/win98me/en-us/vbrun60.exe).

Answer (score 4):

Your friend will need the VB6 runtime files to run any VB6 programs. You can find them on [Microsoft's site](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=bf9a24f9-b5c5-48f4-8edd-cdf2d29a79d5&displaylang=en).

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to generate an installer project.  There are a number of dependencies for the VB6 runtime (http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=bf9a24f9-b5c5-48f4-8edd-cdf2d29a79d5)

Answer (score 1):

He probably needs the [VB runtimes](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=7b9ba261-7a9c-43e7-9117-f673077ffb3c).
But you should look into creating a proper msi installer package for you project.
There is a free one from MS to use with VB6 called the [Visual Studio Installer 1.1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=5fbbc453-cd04-4562-a66e-5c21436e6f56).

Answer (score 0):

Not much information to go on, if you have more, that would be helpful.  I'm just guessing, but, your friend's computer may not have the [VB6 runtime](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=bf9a24f9-b5c5-48f4-8edd-cdf2d29a79d5&displaylang=en) installed.  If he's willing, he should try installing it and see if that fixes the problem.